# Where is the JBoss EAP 7 log pattern format documentation?

Tags: logging, jboss6.x

Where is the JBoss EAP 6 log pattern format documentation? It seems to have some format characters that are different from log4j or logback (such as %K and %s).

A number of searches only turn up results for older jboss versions which don't have the full set of characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [FormatStringParser source code](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/main/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/formatters/FormatStringParser.java) is probably the best bet.

Here is a list of the format characters that differ from log4j:

```
%s  the message (like %m) including exception stack traces
%m  the message, suppressing exception stack traces
%E  exception stack trace
%K  adds terminal-based colorization
%k  log resource key (for localization)
%z  time zone
%P  localized log level name
```

See also [RedHat's documentation](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/170083).

Comment: All the urls are outdate

Comment: @HerrDerb I updated the source code link. The RedHat link still seems to be relevant if you have a RedHat account.